# Can not connect QNA maker to Azure Bot Service

Tags: bots, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am facing with the problem because I can not connect qna maker bot to azure bot service. On qna maker platform everything works good, but when I go to bot service and test in web chat it does not work, it just repeats message I typed. I have already coppied QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey, and the QnAEndpointHostName from QNA maker to bot service settings. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNETW.png)

Answer (score 1):

The responses appear to be coming from the Basic template.  Please try creating a bot using the **Question and Answer** template:

[image]

This will add the **Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices** package, with a QnAMakerDialog.